# Distribute Django App in portable file (windows .exe file for example)

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller, python-packaging, software-packaging

I have a Django App and I would like to distribute my App for Windows, Mac and Linux users.

I have read that Pyinstaller can help me to package my App but I dont know how to create portable App which starts local server on local user
`s desktop.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!